# What is the correct collocation for holding classes as a teacher?

Tags: collocations, formal-language

I'm preparing a work experience letter in which I am expected to include my responsibilities in previous companies. In one of the companies I was holding some classes for other staff. But I'm not sure what is the formal, common and correct way of saying:

*"Holding Object Orientation classes as a teacher for the IT staff"*

To clarify, I don't know which **verb** (holding, teaching conducting, etc) could imply that I was the one who held the class and also was the teacher.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Don't forget to include both prepared and taught. The work of getting the lessons ready is also very important. If you only did the class teaching part it has less prestige on your work experience letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see this in a variety of ways.  You

...taught OOP concepts to IT staff.

...taught IT staff OOP concepts.

...taught classes on OOP concepts.

...conducted classes for IT staff, in which OOP concepts were presented.

**held** and **ran** could be used as less formal synonyms for **conducted**.

This answer is from a grammatical perspective; for advice on resume writing, you would ask elsewhere.

Comment: thanks, so my responsibility was: "conducting OOP classes for IT staff". Is this correct?

Comment: That is certainly a viable way of stating things, although as I wrote, this is not resume-writing advice but English language advice. A resume-writing pundit would tell you whether the past tense or the participle was preferred.

Comment: "conducting" may make it sound like someone else was teaching it. Just say "teaching".

Comment: @LukeSawczak: I see, then what about conducting a presentation? If I was in charge of preparing and delivering it, the can I say I was conducting the presentation?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, This is my final sentence: "Conducting programming classes and teaching OOP concepts to the IT staff." How is this?

Comment: @Bahman_Aries: Are you describing two different responsibilities, or are you saying "Conducted programming classes **in which** I taught OOP concepts to the IT staff"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: No, just one responsibility which is what you said. I guess I should use your exact sentence.